# How can i pass data from window method to the data function in a Vuejs app

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to pass data from `window` method to the `data` function of a vuejs component

here is my window function

```
window.authenticate = function(pid, receiptKey) {
  console.log("Authentication");
  console.log(this)
  localStorage.setItem("pid",pid)
  alert("pid="+pid+"receipt="+receiptKey)
  window.pid=pid
  window.receiptKey = receiptKey
}
```

Data function:

```
 data: () => ({
    pid: 0,
    receipt: 0
  }),
```

trying to set the Pid and receipt key mounted, where am I wrong ?

```
mounted: function (){

 this.pid = window.pid
 alert(this.pid)
 this.receipt = window.receiptKey

}
```

Comment: what's the exact issue?

Comment: I am getting pid and receiptKey from a alient apk in a window method as above (window.authenticacte) now I have to use the pid and receiptkey inside my vuejs app, but cant assign the values of pid and receipt key inside the vuejs app, its in the window scope and not in app so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and found that the created lifecycle hook can be used for this purpose as below

1) we need to bind the window method with component method, window.authenticate to loginCall in the below example, and it all works.

```
created: function () {
        // `this` points to the vm instance
        console.log('a is: ' + this.a)
        // window.somefunc = this.greet.bind(this);
        window.authenticate = this.loginCall.bind(this)
    },


  methods: {

  loginCall: function (pid, receipt) {
}
```